# How to column value shows null or 0 with id wise

Tags: mysql-error-1064

Hi i am beginner of PHP i have query how to show column value show null or zero with id i try below query but this are delete my all bigimage2 in product5 (table name)

mysql_query("UPDATE product5 SET bigimage2 = NULL WHERE bigimage2 = 0");

want insert column shows null with respective row id

above query is run properly but they shows all id  in product5 shows null i want selected id column value is null not all id

Comment: What actually is happening when you run that query, and why is that not expected?

Comment: Given the tag you've got a syntax error in your SQL. Besides that it's unclear what you're aiming for or asking. The title says something of showing, your SQL is updating something and the last sentence says you want to insert a column?!

Comment: above query is run properly but they shows all id  in product5 shows null i want selected id column value is null not all id

Answer (score 0):

Please put the unique I'd on where condition not other. Because Run time update only one record not many.

Example : Update table set field= value where id=id value